# JSON desde PHP, recorrer con JQUERY

Tags: jquery, json

He generado un JSON en un PHP con datos de MySQL con el siguiente código:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");

while($spot = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dbspots)) {
    $jsonspots[] = $spot;
}

print_r($jsonspots);
```

Esto me genera esta salida:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [freq] => 14017
            [spotcall] => RN9N/M
            [time] => 1503318960
            [comment] => RDA SV-09
            [spotter] => RN9N
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [freq] => 14140
            [spotcall] => RA70MG
            [time] => 1503318900
            [comment] => 
            [spotter] => UB8CIF
        )

)
```

Tengo varias dudas...

1.- ¿La generación del JSON está bien?

2.- ¿Como puedo recorrerlo con JQUERY para obtener los datos? `freq = nnn` etc.

Comment: El JSon no está bien. Los elementos en JSon están encapsulados entre llaves { } o entre corchetes si es un array []. Los string se representan entre comillas "" igual que el nombre del campo. Además, los distintos campos se separan mediante comas. Para probar tu JSon puedes hacerlo en esta página https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Si agregas la llamada `$.ajax` que realizas te muestro cómo recorrer el contenido del json en tu propio código.

Answer (score 1):

**¿La generación del JSON está bien?**

Para generar un JSON desde PHP debes hacer uso de la función [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode):

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");

while($spot = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dbspots)) {
    $jsonspots[] = $spot;
}

echo(json_encode($jsonspots));
```

**¿Como puedo recorrerlo con JQUERY para obtener los datos? freq = nnn etc.**

No necesitas jQuery para iterar el contenido de una variable.

Para iterar el contenido de la respuesta desde javascript puedes usar cualquier tipo de bucle, por ejemplo un [bucle `for ... in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for...in).

A continuación tienes un script PHP autónomo con el que puedes probar el funcionamiento:

```
<?php
/* Comprobamos si es la petición POST lanzada */
if (isset($_POST['datos'])) {
    $datos = Array (
        0 => Array (
            'freq' => 14017,
            'spotcall' => 'RN9N/M',
            'time' => 1503318960,
            'comment' => 'RDA SV-09',
            'spotter' => 'RN9N',
        ),
        1 => Array (
            'freq' => 14140,
            'spotcall' => 'RA70MG',
            'time' => 1503318900,
            'comment' => '',
            'spotter' => 'UB8CIF',
        ),
    );
    /* Devolvemos la cabecera adecuada para los datos generados */
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    die(json_encode($datos));
}
?><script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
/* Preparamos la consulta XHR */
$.ajax({
    method: 'post',
    /* La lanzamos a la misma URL */
    url: '<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>',
    /* Datos de envío de prueba */
    data: {
        'datos': true,
    },
    /* Solicitamos un JSON de retorno */
    dataType: 'json',
}).done(function(datos) {
    /* Iteramos por cada elemento devuelto en la variable "datos" */
    for (dato in datos) {
        /* Agregamos un párrafo al <div> con el contenido */
        $( '#resultado' ).append( "<p>Valor de 'frec' (" + dato + "): " + datos[dato].freq + "</p>" );
    }
});
</script>
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

Comment: Oscar, gracias por las contestaciones. Seguro que no me explico bien, soy MUY novato. La cuestión es que el PHP es solo la consulta a la BDD, no hace falta enviarle ningún parámetro y su resultado es el que describo en el trozo que he descrito como "salida" y eso es lo que tengo que intentar pintar dentro de un DOM, por eso la fijación con el JQuery. ¿Me explico muy mal? :(

Comment: La parte de PHP la he modificado, ahora la salida es una línea tal que así...    [{"freq":"14283.1","spotcall":"VE7RAC","time":"1503330360","comment":null,"spotter":"W4GHS"},{"freq":"7095","spotcall":"EA5RKD","time":"1503330360","comment":"DME 37138","spotter":"EA7SS"}]

Comment: Perfecto, esa es la salida correcta. Con mi código javascript podrás pintar lo que quieras en el DOM, jQuery te ayuda a modificar el DOM, pero no lo necesitas para recorrer los valores que obtienes del PHP.

Comment: ¿Qué tal lo llevas? ¿Necesitas más ayuda o aclaración? Si necesitas algo dímelo, si la respuesta te resolvió las dudas y el problema agradecería que marcaras la respuesta como correcta, gracias.

Comment: Estoy probando Oscar, gracias por la ayuda... Ya puedo iterar el resultado de la consulta con el código que me has pasado. Es época complicada. XD.

Comment: Cualquier cosa que necesites dilo. Por lo pronto te agradecería que marcaras la respuesta como correcta antes de que pase el tiempo y se olvide :)

Comment: Lo he hecho, pero me dice que no la marca publicamente, :O porque soy nuevo... :/

Comment: No te preocupes, te voté la pregunta positiva para darte 5 puntos de reputación. Poco a poco subirás y podrás marcarlas de inmediato, por lo pronto hay que esperar 24 o 48 horas tras marcarla para que se haga efectivo. ¡Gracias y bienvenido a la comunidad! :)